# Replacing values in multiple columns of a dataframe based on numeric ranges

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of values for multiple variables, and I want to replace all the numeric values with a character which will label a specific numeric range.  I do NOT want equal ranges, so cut() is not an option so far as I understand.

In the following code, if I generate the dataframe and then run any one or two of the replacement commands, they do exactly what I want them to do.  But when I run them all together, the final table populates with all "f" values.

```
#Generate test dataframe

test1<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1000,100,rep=TRUE)))

#Duplicate dataframe so you can go back and reality check category labels against original data

test<-data.frame(test1)

#These are my replacement commands

  test[test <10] <- "a"
  test[test >=10 & test <25] <- "b"
  test[test >=25 & test <50] <- "c"
  test[test >=50 & test <100] <- "d"
  test[test >=100 & test <500] <- "e"
  test[test >=500] <- "f"
```

single-run any of the replacement commands and you'll see the variables with those values replaced with the corresponding letter.  All I want is this in all values, in all columns, for this dataset.  The ultimate purpose is so I can create a frequency table of the variables by the specified ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cut` to create the labels based on specifying the `breaks`.  For multiple columns, use `lapply` from `base R` to loop over the columns, apply the `cut` and assign back to the dataset of interest

```
test[] <- lapply(test, function(x) 
     cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 10, 25, 50, 100, 500, Inf), labels = letters[1:6]))
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks!  While I'm at it, more for understanding than anything else, what is the meaning of the "-Inf" and "Inf" elements in the breaks?

Comment: @DanM It is to specify the values that are below 10 and above 500 to place in two buckets

Comment: And just from curiosity, any idea what was wrong in my original code?  Your solution is far more elegant, but I still don't understand why my original statements worked individually and not as a group.

Comment: @DanM The issue is that once you change the value to character strings, the columns are no longer numeric.  You may need to create a copy of the dataset and do the logic on the first data while replacing on the second. i.e. `test[test1 <10] <- "a"`

Comment: Excellent @akrun, thank you for your incredibly quick help!